# Paginate a mapped array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I am trying to paginate over an array
I am fairly new to react and don't know where to start

I am trying to paginate this list of events so it only shows 9 events on the page
and when there are more you can click on 2 or 3 etc to see more
and I have no idea how to implement pagination

```
class EventsList extends PureComponent {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getAllEvents();
  }

  getEvent(eventId) {
    this.props.getEvent(eventId);
  }

  addEvent = event => {
    this.props.addEvent(event);
  };

  render() {
    const now = Moment();
    const { events, authenticated } = this.props;
    const eventsList = events.sort((a, b) =>{
     return a.id - b.id;
   });

    if (!authenticated) return <Redirect to="/login" />;

    return <div>
        <Paper className="styles" elevation={4}>
          <h1>Coming Events</h1>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Event Name</th>
                <th>Starts</th>
                <th>Ends</th>
                <th>Short description</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {eventsList.map(event => <tr key={event.id}>
                  <td>

                <Link className="link" to={`/events/${event.id}`} onClick={() => this.getEvent(event.id)}>
                      {event.name}
                    </Link>
                  </td>

                  {now && <td style={{ border: "2px solid black" }}>

                      {Moment(event.startDate).format("ll")}
                    </td>}
                  {now && <td style={{ border: "2px solid black" }}>

                      {Moment(event.endDate).format("ll")}
                    </td>}

                  <td />

                  <td style={{ border: "2px solid green"  }}>
                    {event.description}
                  </td>

                  <td />
                </tr>)}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <br />
          <br />
          <Link className="link" to={`/addEvent`}>
            Add An Event
          </Link>
        </Paper>
      </div>;
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
    events: state.events,
    event: state.event,
    authenticated: state.currentUser !== null,
    users: state.users === null ? null : state.users
  };
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    getAllEvents,
    getEvent,
    addEvent,
    getUsers
  }
)(EventsList);
```

I am looking at 
http://pagination.js.org
and https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-js-pagination

but I don't get how I should implement it.
If someone can give me some pointers?
or a simple example ?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to keep track of a few items. First the total number of events. Second the current page. Third the number of items per page (a constant you want to set).

Then you can do any number of things to your `events` array to only show those items.

For example, you could use an array slice https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice -- This will give you back a new array with only the items you want.

So to get a second page of items (10 - 19) you would calculate your start and end indexes based on the page number and the number of items per page and then end up with something like.

```
const numberPerPage = 9;
const startIndex = 10; // Computed based on your numbers
const endIndex = startIndex + numPerPage;
const pagedEvents = eventsList.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
```

That will give you a list with only the items for that page. Updating the page number will cause the numbers to change and the list to update.